# Is Camille a male or female name?

Tags: genre-biologique, prénoms

In English, my instinct is that it is more female. But in French, I have seen Camille has been used in both male and female names if I remember correctly. So is this true?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Camille* est un prénom [*épicène*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/epicene). Voir aussi une [liste](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie%3aPr%C3%A9nom_%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne) de tels prénoms.

---

*Camille* can be used for both.  We have a word in French for words which can be used for both sexes without variation: [*épicène*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/epicene). Wikipedia has a [list of such forenames](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie%3aPr%C3%A9nom_%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne)

Comment: Je suis baba d'y trouver _Dorothée_.

Comment: @Joubarc et Philippe?

Comment: J'étais surtout surpris d'apprendre que _Dorothée_ pouvait être utilisé pour un garçon, mais je dois dire que _Philippe_ ne me pose pas de problème.

Answer (score 5):

Used for both, like *Dominique* or *Claude* (among the most frequently used).

Comment: Thanks! Is "Stéphane" also such an example? I thought it was a girl's name at first.

Comment: "Stéphanie" is for girls. I have never met a girl named Yannick. I never knew it was also intended for girls. I know a few women named Annick though. Seems it's not the same origin anyway.

Comment: @subtenante: Indeed it's more biased than I tought, I removed it from the short list. *Stéphane* might occur for a girl [here](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%A9phane_Audran) and [there](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%A9phane_Bissot) but I never met one in real life, as *Stéphanie* is commonly used.

Comment: For the example, the first one coming to my mind is [Camille Saint-Saëns](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_Saint-Sa%C3%ABns)