# Épicène, unisexe ou mixte?

Tags: adjectifs, sens, genre-biologique

Dans ma réponse à la question sur [Camille](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1277/is-camille-a-male-or-female-name), je mentionne qu'on qualifie de tels prénoms d'[*épicènes*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/epicene).

On les qualifie aussi parfois de *mixtes*, ce qui m'a toujours gêné car *mixte* implique pour moi un mélange. Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mixte) ne donne que des définitions impliquant aussi un mélange, mais bizarrement pour la définition

> Qui comprend ou qui concerne des personnes (notamment des jeunes) des deux sexes mêlés ensemble.

propose deux exemples plus proches de l'utilisation pour qualifier les prénoms épicènes:

> *Vélo mixte.* Vélo pour homme ou pour femme.
>   *Garde-robe, pull, tenue mixte. Casquette mixte.*

Mais dans ces exemples j'aurais utilisé [*unisexe*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/unisexe).
Est-ce que *mixte* dans ces usages sans mélange est réellement courant ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans le cas des prénoms, mon interprétation de [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9noms_mixtes) est qu'un prénom mixte est un prénom qui peut être utilisé pour les deux sexes, c'est-à-dire qu'il a une version masculine et une version féminine. Quand en plus ces deux versions ont la même forme, il est également épicène. Par exemple, *Louis(e)* est un prénom mixte mais pas épicène ; *Dominique* est épicène (et donc mixte également).

Quand à l'utilisation de *mixte*, j'aurais moi aussi tendance à la limiter au cas où les deux sexes sont effectivement mélangés, comme pour les écoles, les troupes scoutes, les toilettes… et à utiliser plutôt *unisexe* pour les vêtements.

Cela dit, l'utilisation d'*unisexe* pour signifier « [qui convient à l'un ou l'autre sexe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/unisexe) » est relativement récente (1970), ce qui explique sans doute que *mixte* soit encore mentionné avec cette signification. Donc, pour répondre à ta question, si *mixte* est courant dans ce sens, il est sans doute amené à disparaître au profit d'*unisexe*.

Comment: Nuance intéressante pour les prénoms. À propos d'_unisexe_, le phénomène dans l'habillement (et ailleurs aussi) me semble tout aussi récent.

Answer (score 2):

Juste une opinion (je n'ai pas de meilleures références que les tiennes).

*Épicène* ne semble être employé que lorsque le genre grammatical est aussi en question (*un pianiste*, *une pianiste*). *Mixte* concerne l'emploi par des personnes des deux genres : un vélo mixte ça reste *un* vélo, accordé au masculin, qu'il soit utilisé par un homme ou une femme. Pour parler d'un vélo épicène, il nous faudrait trouver une marque de vélo qui s’utilise à la fois au masculin et au féminin.

Pour un prénom le genre grammatical compte, et certains sont utilisés pour les deux genres, pour ces prénoms-là les deux adjectifs conviennent.

Enfin, pour *unisexe* (qui est très récent d'après [ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=unisexe&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=7)), je pense que c'est l'*intention* de faire une utilisation commune qui passe au premier plan.

Comment: Tiens, j'ai plutôt l'impression contraire : j'ai déjà entendu *prénom épicène* chez des gens qui ne sont pas du genre à lire le dictionnaire de A à Z, alors que *nom épicène* est pour moi cantonné aux grammairiens professionels.

Comment: @Gilles: je ne vois pas vraiment où est la contradiction.

Comment: @Gilles: dis-moi si la modif satisfait le doute exprimé dans ton commentaire.

Comment: À vrai dire je me demande ce que tu veux dire par « lorsque le genre grammatical est aussi en question ». Lorsque le locuteur est incertain du genre ? Lorsque l'objet qualifié peut être de l'un ou l'autre genre ?

Comment: J'espère que c'est clair maintenant, sinon j'abandonne :-)

Answer (score 1):

Dans les usages courants, on utilise le mot « mixte ». Je n'ai jamais entendu le mot épicène prononcé. Ainsi il y a peu de chance que quelqu'un comprenne ce mot :P

Et oui, lorsque que l'on emploie un prénom pour deux genres, on fait un mélange des genres puisque un mot désigne à la fois deux choses différentes.

Comment: _Épicène_ pour qualifier les prénoms s'apprend dans n'importe quel bouquin du genre _Un prénom pour la vie_ que tout futur parent va bien feuilleter un jour. J'ai découvert le sens grammatical en lisant l'entrée du dictionnaire quand j'ai mis le lien dessus.

Comment: Je dois bien avouer qu'_épicène_ ne figurait pas non plus dans mon vocabulaire.

Comment: +1 pour l'aveu de la découverte du mot *épicène*. Portant un prénom de ce type, je n'en ai jamais entendu parlé ni même découvert dans le Lagarde et Michard du lycée (aucun prof' ne l'a mentionné non plus), au hasard d'un roman d'une revue ou d'un journal, encore moins au détour d'une conversation sur ce problème de prénom qui m'a toujours été présenté comme *mixte* ; mot qui certainement aurait attiré mon attention et que je ne vais pas oublier. - Claude

Comment: pour moi aussi : épicène était inconnu au bataillon.

Answer (score 0):

« Mixte » est couramment employé pour désigner le mélange homme-femme. Par exemple on parle d'« école mixte ».

Comment: Je n'ai pas de problème avec mixte pour désigner le mélange, j'en ai un quand il signifie l'adéquation aux deux sexes comme dans le cas des prénoms ou des vêtements. (Et je vois bien comment on est peut-être en train d'ajouter un sens à mixte, peut-être sous l'influence des écoles mixtes d'ailleurs).  Je cherche à savoir si ma réticence est commune.